# How to install Netfilter / enable conntrack events?

Tags: debian, netfilter, ip-conntrack

I have come across this [repo](https://github.com/mirror/dd-wrt/blob/master/src/router/ndpi-netfilter/ndpi-netfilter/INSTALL) and struggle to understand these steps.

I believe this is to enable the Netfilter conntrack events, but I'm not sure.

What do I have to run to get these prompts?

```
--------------------------------------------------------
2. The minimum requirements for the kernel configuration
--------------------------------------------------------

Kernel version >= 4.4

Networking support  --->
  Networking options  --->
  [*] Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter)  --->
        Core Netfilter Configuration  --->
          Netfilter connection tracking support (M/Y)
          Number of custom extend (1) (if patched kernel)
      "connlabel" match support (M)

Check your kernel configuration file.
For non-patched kernel there should be:

  CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m or y
  CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_LABELS=y
  CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLABEL=m
  CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS=y

For patched kernel there should be:

  CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m or y
  CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_CUSTOM=1
  CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS=y
```

**UPDATE:**

I installed `apt install conntrack` as suggested. I'm not sure if the kernel is correctly setup, which is my main question here.

But moving on to the third section, compiling it fails too. I wonder if this is an issue on the repo or the minimum requirements aren't met.

```
admin@de-vpn-1:~/dd-wrt/src/router/ndpi-netfilter$ ./autogen.sh
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:54: installing './compile'
configure.ac:6: installing './missing'
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'example/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'tests/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'tests/unit/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'tests/performance/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'tests/dga/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'rrdtool/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:336: error: required file 'influxdb/Makefile.in' not found
configure.ac:337: error: required file 'tests/do.sh.in' not found
Makefile.am:2: error: required directory ./tests does not exist
```

Comment: If you have the pre-compiled netfilter/conntrack software installed via `apt`, I don't think there's a need to compile a custom version unless you have a clear and specific need for the custom version.  Perhaps your question is more about "How do I configure and use netfilter with connection tracking" than "How do I compile the software from that github repo?"